# POSIX shell: escaping line-continuations in backquote command-substitutions

Tags: shell, sh, posix, language-lawyer, command-substitution

I'm writing a shell, and I'm a little confused by the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03). Say I have the command:

```
echo "`echo "a\\
b"`"
```

Should the shell output

```
ab
```

or

```
a\
b
```

?

In other words, are line continuations removed again after removing the escaping from the text in a command substitution? The POSIX specification appears to specify that line-continuation removal will not happen again, however, all the shells I tested (bash, dash, and busybox's ash) run line-continuation removal again, causing the test script to output `ab`.

Script explanation:

The part of the script that's inside the command-substitution is un-escaped, producing:

```
echo "a\
b"
```

Now, if line-continuation removal is run again, it will remove the backslash-newline pair, producing the command `echo "ab"` inside the command-substitution, otherwise the backslash-newline pair will still be between the `a` and `b`.

Comment: you can run bash in posix mode by `bash --posix` and see how that treats the command

Comment: @IanKenney bash in posix mode produces an identical result to non-posix mode

Comment: I know in the example that you gave, but with the --posix flag set, bash is supposed to be more posix compliant than without.  I Thought it may be useful for you to see how existing shells interpret the specification

Comment: @IanKenney ok. I mentioned that i had tested in several different shells. one of the shells I tested (dash) is designed specifically to implement no more or less than the posix spec.

Comment: @programmerjake that's true. I've checked similar cases and it looks for me like bash work with that code in that way: if you're using gravemarks – first ``\`` is used to escape ``\n`` while writing, second – while invoking. If you write it without ``\\`` – you'll get ``a\nb``. (I didn't say that makes sense...)

Comment: [Check man bash (quoting)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). It's interesting...

Comment: `$( )` is perfectly valid in POSIX sh. It's only pre-POSIX Bourne that doesn't have it -- and backslash handling is **much** simpler in `$()`. Which is to say, I'd suggest amending the title to specify "backticks", if that's the whole of where you have questions.

Comment: There's only _one_ line continuation (the embedded `"..."` string _by itself_ doesn't contain one, due to the `\ ` preceding the newline being escaped as `\\ `), and it stems from the shell interpreting the `\\ ` as single `\ ` _before_ parsing and executing the embedded command, due to use of `\`...\`` (rather than `$(...)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ***Old-style* `` `...` `` command substitutions subject the embedded command to *prior* interpretation of `\` as an escape character**, and only *then* parse and execute it.

  - This passage from the [POSIX shell spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) is key (edited for readability):

  > Within the backquoted style of command substitution, `\` shall retain its literal meaning, except when followed by: `$`, `` ` ``, or `\`.

  - In other words: any embedded `\$`, `` \` ``, and `\\` sequences are treated as *escape sequences* whose 2nd character should be treated *literally*.
  - Thus, `\\<newline>` in your command is reduced to `\<newline>`, because `` `...` `` interprets the `\\` as an *escaped, literal* `\`
  - This interpretation happens *before* the embedded command is parsed and executed.
  - The `\<newline>` in the resulting command is therefore interpreted as a *line continuation* (inside the double-quoted string), which effectively *removes* the newline.
  - Therefore, the double-quoted string is effectively parsed as literal `ab`, and that is what is passed to the inner `echo` call.
  - In `bash`, you can verify this processing by setting debugging options: `set -xv`
- ***Modern* syntax `$(...)` *avoids such surprises*** by providing **a truly independent quoting context**.

  - To quote from [the "Rationale for Shell and Utilities" part of the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03) (emphasis added):

  > Because of these inconsistent behaviors, **the backquoted variety of command substitution is not recommended for new applications that nest command substitutions or attempt to embed complex scripts**.

  - With `$(...)`, the escaped line continuation in the embedded double-quoted string is retained (in `bash`, `dash`, `ksh` and `zsh`):

    ```sh
    echo "$(echo "a\\
    b")"

    # Output
    a\
    b
    ```
  - Another reason to prefer `$(...)` is that it works the same in `bash`, `dash`, `ksh` and `zsh`, which is not true of `` `...` ``, whose behavior differs in `ksh` (see below).

---

#### Compliance in major POSIX-like shells - `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`

- In `ksh` (verified with version `93u+`), your  command *breaks*, because `ksh` *requires* embedded `"` chars. inside `` `...` `` to be escaped as `\"` - which is a deviation from the standard.
  Syntax `$(...)` does *not* have this requirement.
- `bash`, `dash`, and `zsh` process your `` `...` ``-based command as required by the spec (in the case of `bash`, whether or not it is run in POSIX-compatibility mode).

  - Note that these shells *also* support `\"`-escaped as double quotes inside `` `...` `` as `ksh` requires.
  - Arguably, supporting this is a deviation from the standard, given that `"` is *not* among the characters that form an escape sequence when preceded by `\` in the context of `` `...` ``; e.g., `` echo "`echo \"a   b\"`" `` should result in `"a b"`, not `a   b`.

---

#### Optional reading: cross-shell testing

If you find yourself needing to compare the behavior of POSIX-like shells frequently, consider use of [`shall`](https://github.com/mklement0/shall), my CLI and REPL for invoking shell scripts or commands with multiple POSIX-like shells.

By default, it targets `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` (whichever ones are installed).

If you put your command in script `./tst`, for instance, you would invoke `shall` as follows:

```sh
shall ./tst
```

which yields something like:

[image: <code>shall</code> sample output]

Note how invocation with `ksh` failed, because `ksh` requires `"` inside a `` `...` `` command substitution to be escaped as `\"`.
Again, using `$(...)` would bypass this problem.

#### Installation of `shall` from the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shall) (Linux and macOS)

<sup>Note: Even if you don't use Node.js, `npm`, its package manager, works across platforms and is easy to install; try

[`curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash`](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install)</sup>

With [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed, install as follows:

```sh
[sudo] npm install shall -g
```

**Note**:

- Whether you need `sudo` depends on how you installed Node.js and whether you've [changed permissions later](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions); if you get an `EACCES` error, try again with `sudo`.
- The `-g` ensures [*global* installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) and is needed to put `shall` in your system's `$PATH`.

#### Manual installation (any Unix platform with `bash`)

- Download [this `bash` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/shall/stable/bin/shall) as `shall`.
- Make it executable with `chmod +x shall`.
- Move it or symlink it to a folder in your `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` (macOS) or `/usr/bin` (Linux).

Comment: i was missing that the unescaped content goes through all the steps of parsing again, the first step after splitting into lines is removing line-continuations.

Comment: @programmerjake: Got it - I hadn't even questioned that aspect; that the embedded command is parsed again is clearly how it works in practice, but it's not obvious to me from the spec.